# Converting date column into weekday column with data from previous column. Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime, weekday

I don't know why I can't figure this out. I've tried a million different ways to do this, but no cookie.

```
    wkdp = dte.dt.dayofweek #gives only the index(0-monday,6-sunday)
    print (wkdp)

    wkdp = dte.dt.dayofweek #gives only the index(0-monday,6-sunday)
    print (wkdp)
​
    0      0
    1      1
    2      2
    3      3
    4      4
      ..
    499    2
    500    3
    501    4
    502    0
    503    1
    Name: Date, Length: 504, dtype: int64
```

So here I can get the integer value. But I cannot change it to the day of the week string. It's a 503 column of data and some of the examples that I have seen don't use variables to convert but individual dates. Can someone help me out. I have tried

```
    date.weekday()
```

and nothing. I have also tried

```
    dp_weekday = date(date_parse).weekday() 
    #Convert weekday column data into string value
    days = 
    {0:'Monday',1:'Tuesday',2:'Wednesday',3:'Thursday',4:'Friday',5:'Saturday',6:'Sunday'}
```

Comment: what exactly is your question? What do you have and what do you want?

Comment: Have you tried map()?  You can try this: dte.dt.dayofweek.map(days)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are looking for:

```
wkdp = dte.dt.strftime('%A')
print(wkdp)
```